# Weblogic health monitoring feature

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx

Inside the weblogic console, when you click on a deployment, there is a tab named 'Monitoring' and a subtab named 'Health'.

How can i expose my application health to this tab? Is there a developer's guide somewhere?

[image]

To clarify what i want to do: Output my application background process states to this 'Health' monitoring page in the WLS admin page.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: JMX is probably the way to expose data, but that tab might be locked to only show WLS stuff. Perhaps you can write your own dashboard page, or extend the WLS console (see the docs).

Comment: Have considered writing my own dashboard. Jconsole does a great job already too. But I would like to use that tab to standardise application health monitoring for administrators.

Comment: Still researching on how this can be done. It would be a shame if i can not hook into it - since that is the intention of the Console software.

Comment: Still searching. Amazed It's so hard to figure this out for Weblogic!

Answer (score 2):

The guide [Configuring and Using the Diagnostics Framework for Oracle WebLogic Server](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13714/toc.htm) might be worth a look. It describes how to configure Weblogic to monitor your custom JMX beans, among other things. I don't know if this framework is used by the Health tab you're referring to, though.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it and hopefully get back.

Answer (score 0):

Use the provided framework and tag libraries to [Extend the Administration Console (11g)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13745/toc.htm). If you can't add your own data to the "Health" tab, you should at least be able to add your own sibling tab to that page.

Comment: Interesting read. I will definitely consider Console extension.